# For loop is throwing "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" after first iteration it is not iterating 2nd item in the list

Tags: python-2.7

I have one list with directories. I need to go each directory of a list and execute some command. like this I need to process entire list. But after first iteration it is throwing OSError. Please find the below code and help me.

CODE:

```
ls_2 = ['build', 'flexiserver', 'fvntools', 'gbuild', 'sample']
for dir in ls_2:
    print ("Inside for loop")
    os.chdir(dir)
    ls_2 = os.listdir('.')
    print ("Inside dir %s %s"  %(dir, ls_2))
    subprocess.call('buildme.sh')
```

Comment: Looks like what one of those folders doesn't contain a `buildme.sh`.

Comment: Actually I am exporting the buildme.sh before ierating the loop so that it will available to execute in all directories.                                                                                                                              CODE: os.chdir('scm_scripts')
        os.system('export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)')
        os.chdir('..')
        print ("After export scm_scripts path is" , os.getcwd())
        for dir in ls_2:
            print ("Inside for loop")

Comment: `os.system('export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)')` does nothing.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Are the folder nested inside one another?

One possible reason is all these folders inside the same folder. In that case, after you get into build, you want to go one level back before you access flexiserver.

Your code seems to be looking for the flexiserver folder that is inside the build folder but there is no such folder there.

Comment: Folders are not nested. All folders which are present in the list are in same path.

Comment: have you tried going one level back before you access the second item?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. I missed simple logic. Thanks alot :)